# Webpack 3.9.1 - How do I combine LESS files into one CSS file?

Tags: html, css, node.js, webpack

I'm very new to Webpack and I'm not certain how to handle LESS. I want to have many LESS files and I want them to compile into one CSS file after I run `npm run build`. This would result in a `style.css` file which includes everything.

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: 
        [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ]

    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

How exactly do I configure webpack to make it combine all LESS files into one CSS file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a plugin called `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to achieve this. According to their documentation, this plugin moves all the required `*.css` modules in entry chunks into a separate CSS file. So your styles are no longer inlined into the JS bundle, but in a separate CSS file (`styles.css`). Now of course, in your case, you will first have to parse your `.less` files to `.css` and then bundle them up into a single file.

You can modify your webpack config like so:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: "css-loader"
      })
    },
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ <---- Use the plugin here to extract the styles
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: "css-loader"
      })
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: ['file-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader'
    }
  ]
},
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
]};
```

Comment: Shouldn't the loader for `.less` be the `less-loader` instead of the `css-loader`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`extract-text-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to make one css file. But only do this for a production build not while you are developing.

I would look at using the Webpack [`less-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader). It covers a production build [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader#in-production)